# About normal subgroup of a finite quasisimple group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $G\neq \{e\}$ be a finite non-abelian group. We say $G$ is quasi-simple if $G=[G,G]$ and $G/Z(G)$ is simple.

Let $G$ be a quasi-simple group. It is not so difficult to show that if $N$ is a non-trivial normal subgroup of $G$, then $N\leq Z(G)$. Indeed if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and $N$ is not contained in $Z(G)$, then necessarily $[G,G]\leq N$, whence $N=G$.

Now my question is about its converse. Suppose $G$ is a finite non-abelian group such that all its non-trivial normal subgroups are central. Can we conclude that $G$ is quasi-simple?

My attempt : Given the hypothesis it is immediate that $G/Z(G)$ is a finite simple group. We want to show $[G,G]=G$. If not then once again by hypothesis $[G,G]\leq Z(G)$, which implies that $G/Z(G)$ is abelian. Since it is also simple, we conclude that $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic, whence $G$ is abelian, a contradiction. Is this correct or am I saying something silly here!

Thanks in advance for any kind of comments or suggestions.

Comment: Your argument looks OK to me, except that you should replace "non-trivial normal subgroup" by "proper normal subgroup" throughout. The trivial normal subgroup of a quasisimple group has order $1$ and is central. But the group $G$ is not central, but it is not proper.

Comment: Thank you very much! Yeah actually I meant proper by saying "non trivial" but yes that's not the right terminology. "Proper" is the right word. Thanks once again.